# How to account for ties in test scores when your finding out lowest and highest scores from from 3 test scores?

Tags: c++

For my C++ assignment I have to  find Lowest, highest, and average of test scores from a set of three test scores. What extra code do i need in case Two or all three have the same test score when finding the highest and lowest test score in C++? Here is the code i have so far it runs fine except for if two of the scores are the same.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int _midtermgrade, _projectaverage, _homeworkaverage, average;
cout << " Please enter your midterm grade:" << endl;
cin >> _midtermgrade;
cout << "Please enter your project average:" << endl;
cin >> _projectaverage;
cout << " Please enter your homework average:" << endl;
cin >> _homeworkaverage;
if((_midtermgrade >_projectaverage)&&(_midtermgrade >_homeworkaverage)){ 
    cout << "Your highest score is your midterm " <<  _midtermgrade endl;
}
if ((_projectaverage >_midtermgrade)&(_projectaverage>_homeworkaverage)) 
cout << "Your highest score is your project " << _projectaverage << endl;
}
if((_homeworkaverage >_projectaverage&(_homeworkaverage>_midtermgrade)){ 
cout << "Your highest score is your homework "<< _homeworkaverage <<endl;
}
if((_midtermgrade < _projectaverage)&&(_midtermgrade<_homeworkaverage)){ 
    cout << "Your lowest score is your midterm " << _midtermgrade<< endl;
}
if((_projectaverage<_midtermgrade)&&(_projectaverage<_homeworkaverage)){
    cout << "Your lowest score is your project "<< _projectaverage<<endl;
}   
if ((_homeworkaverage<_projectaverage)&&_midtermgrade)){  
    cout 

<< "Your lowest score is your homework " << _homeworkaverage << endl;
}

average =((_midtermgrade * 20 +_projectaverage* 40 + _homeworkaverage*15)
    / (20 + 40 + 15)); 
cout << "Your currentaverage is " << average <<endl;

if (_midtermgrade < 70){
    cout << "You have a failing grade on the midterm." << endl;
}
 else   
        cout << "You have a passing grade on the midterm." << endl;

if (_projectaverage < 70){
    cout << "You have a failing grade on the project." << endl;}
    else
        cout << "You have a passing grade on the project." << endl;

if (_homeworkaverage < 70){
    cout << "You have a failing grade on the homework." << endl;
}   else
        cout << "You have a passing grade on the homework." << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a first glance at your code, I could tell right away that you're doing too much work. You should be using functions and function calls to make your code more modular. This will reduce code bloat, make your code easier to read/follow and make your code easier to maintain if you ever want to add/change something to it in the future.

For instance, you could create both a min and max function to find the highest and lowest test scores.

**For example...**

```
int MAX(int test_score1, int test_score2, int test_score3)
{
    if(conditional statement)
        return something;
}
```

After you implement your min and max functions, create another function to find the average test score in the same way.

As for your original question, if you have two or three test scores which are the same, then the simplest approach would be to use the logical operator `==` to test for equality between all three test scores. All you have to figure out is where in your control flow (program) do you want to test equality of all three test scores.

To learn more about functions see this [C++ online tutorial page](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/14-a-first-look-at-functions/). If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to click the checkmark on the left. Otherwise, if you have more questions, feel free to leave me a comment and I will try to help you out.